# Prestashop Tax Off When VAT Number Inserted

Tags: prestashop

In my shop, when a user inserts a VAT number, the tax value desapears. I understand its comon practice abroad. But here in Portugal, the tax value is allways present.

I tried with Vat module and normal "NIF" field, but neither appears with tax value, or in the final invoice.

Im running, prestashop 1.6.0.8.

Someone with the same problem as me, another portuguese, says it got it workgin doing the folloying instrutions from a spanish tutorial:

In controllers/AuthController.php
Change

```
If ($country->need_identification_number && (!Tools::getValue(‘dni’) || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’))))
```

To

```
//if ($country->need_identification_number && (!Tools::getValue(‘dni’) || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’))))
if (!Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’)))
```

And in “controllers/”AddressController.php,
Change

```
if ($country->isNeedDni() && (!Tools::getValue(‘dni’) || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’))))
```

To

```
//if ($country->isNeedDni() && (!Tools::getValue(‘dni’) || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’))))
if (!Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue(‘dni’)))
```

But this code is for 1.5.x presta and mine is 1.6.0.8 and i guess dni is ther tax name.

Heres the source: http://postly.elnostreraco.com/como-hacer-el-dni-opcional-en-prestashop-y-por-que-desconfiar-si-te-hacen-tocar-codigo-base/

Comment: Well disagree with you, since the only form of resolution i think its editing the code. But the only solutions i've seen are for versions earlier than mine.

Comment: Well that was not my objective, And i didn't noticed the code issue.

Comment: Well, get the work done for me,  that was not my objective, And i didn't noticed the code issue.

Since this is a specific problem for a minority of countries in ps theres not much reply to this question in comunity foruns.

the only pointers i got was to edit AuthController.php and AddressController.php in 1.5.x version, since mine is 1.6. the file is very diferent. 

I got some code here to test , but i think it will not match my own AuthController.php in 1.6.0.8 version.

But no worries, if you are a moderator  feel free to delete this post. I will continue my quest . Thanks,

Comment: Not a mod (they have diamonds next their names). You are *starting* to provide useful information, so please include it, and the code, in the body of your post (using the little "edit" button below it). It may not match your file, but you are at least giving a reader **something** to go off of.

Comment: Ok, sorry about the attitude.

Comment: Links are always good (and I don't think you can ever violate a license by linking). Regardless, your question is *far* better now. I hope you get help! Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP user :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for the patience, all the same! :D

Answer (score 1):

When using the VAT Module you can select a country. For users from that country (the one you selected in the module config), VAT **will** be added. For users from other countries, VAT **will not** be calculated, which, i believe, is in accordance with EU Law.

Comment: I understand that but here in Portugal, if a store is selling to the common public,  with VAT or no VAT number, the tax value is allways calculated. 

I have resolved that, by supressing the Vat field in the registration form.
And if a user needs it, just inserts it on observation box. This seems rather rude, but the final invoice is issued on another accounting software. 

But the question remains, what if i wanted to do that,..

Comment: right, i understand, but my belief is that the vat module does just that, at least for the 3 german webshops i manage. Regardless if a german customer enters a VAT number or not, if the shipping address is germany, VAT is always added, for foreign customers (with a foreign shipping address), VAT is **not** added if they enter a valid VAT number. Is it maybe related to your "localization > taxes" settings or the setting of the module? is the module the latest version (i remember there being some issues with earlier versions)?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/159919-vat-number/page-2#entry1471583):

Your PrestaShop is misconfigured. When no "Your country" set in module "vatnumber" and your customer fill in the vat_number field, presta shop will force tax-free price.

I've selected country in this module (but not vat number validation) and it worked - user enter vat code or not, VAT is applied.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for!