# Prestashop free tax when VAT Number is inserted

Tags: prestashop, user-registration

Im using Prestashop 1.7 and module VAT number (https://github.com/PrestaShop/vatnumber) is descontinuated.

I need that when a customer is registered (out of spain) and insert a vat number  this customer can order without taxes.

We dont need VIES validation, customer can insert any number and we will check this number offline and after purchase.

It is possible?

I dont know if I can get free tax to determinated customer or determinated customer group. I dont know how to proceed.Functionality explainde here ([Prestashop Tax Off When VAT Number Inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489007/prestashop-tax-off-when-vat-number-inserted)) doesnt work today.

Best regards